# How to disable ring ringtone volume change

Tags: android, button, controls, volume

I'm doing an app where I control the soundeffects by `OnKeyUp-Keycode.VolumeDown/Up`. This works fine but the problem is that when hitting the VolumeUp/Down buttons a ringtone volume control is also invoked putting a GUI widget on top of my app and increasing/decreasing the ringtone volume as well.

How can I get past this? I want sole control of the volume buttons while running my app.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use [onKeyUp (int keyCode, KeyEvent event)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html#onKeyUp%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) I suggest you set your return value to `true`

> Returns
>
> If you handled the event, return true. 
>   If you want to allow the event to be handled by the next receiver, return false.